# Meteor: Publish Data from External API and insert same data to DB

Tags: meteor

I have a requirement where i need to publish the data from the external API and then insert that data to MongoDB as well. As of now what i have implemented is fetching the data from external API and insert into db and published the same date which works fine but user can see the delay in this implementation.

Requirement is Call the External API when the value from the Dropdown is selected and publish the same data in the templateName template and insert it into DB in the background.

How do i publish the data that come from external API and insert the same ? I am using the Meteor.call and calling server method in the Events function.

```
<template name="category">
  <select id="category">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    {{#each categories}}
        <option value="{{V}}">{{V}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>

<template name="templateName">
   {{a}}
   {{b}}
</template>

Template.category.events({
   "change #category": function (event, template) {
      var cat = $(event.currentTarget).val();
      Meteor.call('serverMethod',cat, function(err, response) {
        Collections.insert(response.data);
        BlazeLayout.render('MainContainer',{main: "templateName"} );
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, the one who make call to external API is `server`. Why you send the response from server to client, then insert the response from client to server to DB? This is the reason you find delay.

It will much faster that after server get the response, then insert the response to DB

This will insert response to DB:

```
Meteor.methods({
    methodName: function () {
        var response = HTTP.call(method, url, options, asyncCallback);
        if (response) {
            Collections.insert(response.data);
        }
        return response
    }
});
```

Response on client:

```
Template.category.events({
 "change #category": function (event, template) {
    var cat = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    Meteor.call('serverMethod',cat, function(err, response) {
      Session.set('apiData', response.data)
      BlazeLayout.render('MainContainer',{main: "templateName"} );
    });
  }
});



 Template.templateName.helpers({
    apiData: function () {
        return Session.get('apiData')
    }
});
```

You don't need to subscribe. Data is already at the client via method call and pass to templateName via `Session.get()`. If you using subscribe, it will much slower to arrive at client and double data which is inefficient

Comment: But why Session.get('apidata') is returned in catergory helper ? shouldn't it be in templateName helper.? Catergory is dropdown template name. and one more thing whatever data has been inserted i have published and subscribing to that,  as of now.. i dont have to do that anymore rite ?

Comment: Yes templateName. I have edit it. You don't need to subscribe. Data is already at the client via method call. And pass the data via `Session.get()`

Comment: hi, your code works very well, i have one more doubt that i wanted to clarify, i have one more method in the server that updates the Category dropdown list, right now i am doing it by button click, but i want to remove that button and call that method onLoad of my app as well as at every regular interval. how do i do that ? thanks alot...

Comment: Hm I don't understand. Might be better if you create new question so we can take a look this new issue.

Comment: i think my insertion to db is synchronous and after insertion oly response is returned to client. how do i make my insertion to db async ?

Comment: How you sure it sync? By default, method will run async, except you execute `Meteor.wrapAsync()` inside method

Comment: it was lil slow so thought its sync, i am calling api this way -> var response = HTTP.call("GET", "URL"); and then insert the response and return the response. is it correct ?

Comment: Slow or not depend on your external api giving you the data. Meteor done a good job by making method run async by default

Comment: thats cool!!! hey i have raised one more question, can u pls look into it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334770/meteor-calling-external-api-multiple-times-with-different-parameter-and-publis

Comment: right now i am doing a api call onchange of select, but looks like requirement might change and i might have to call api for all the values that are in select . How do i this ?? Note dat data in select comes from another api. I jus have to remove the select field and do api call onload and for every category do one more call to get category details.