# Meteor : Calling External API multiple times with different parameter and publishing the data

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a requirement where i need to call the same external API multiple times but with different parameter every time, every call result should be shown in tabular form in the UI and all those results should be inserted into db.

What is the best way to do so that there is no delay in the UI ?

This is what i am trying as of now

Server Code :

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.methods({
      getLocation: function(){
          this.unblock();
          var userAddress = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
          for(var i=0;i<userAddress;i++){
            var response = HTTP.call("GET","URL"+userMacAddress[i]+"/track");
            if(response){
              result = response.data;
              var dateTime = new Date();
              DeviceView.insert({
                  'dateTime' : dateTime,
                  'aps' : result.aps|| '',
                  'Mac' : result.Mac
              });
              //keep pushing the repsone to array
            }
          }
        }
        //return the array
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no need to put the `Meteor.methods()` block inside `Meteor.startup()`.

I'm not exactly sure what type of "delay" you're trying to prevent. Given that you're using the synchronous version of `HTTP.call` I'm going to assume this is a server-side method.

If the results are going to be displayed on the page, you can simply use an `{{#each}}{{/each}}` block in your `template` and the results will automatically populate on the page as soon as they are inserted and you don't neccessarily need to return the array from the method for each document to appear in the UI.

Say for instance that you want to display the results in an unordered list, in your template file you do something like this:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    ...
    <ul>
    {{#each devices}}
    {{> device}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    ...
    </template>
```

This will pass the context of each item to the child template "device", so you can make a template named "device":

```
<template name="device">
<li> The Mac Address is: {{Mac}} {{#if aps}} The APS is: {{aps}} Recorded at: {{dateTime}}</li>
</template>
```

In your JS you will need

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    devices: function() {
       return DeviceView.find({});
    }
});
```

As soon as each `insert` is fired, the `<li>` element for that record will be inserted into the DOM automatically.

Keep in mind that the results can only get returned as quickly as each `HTTP.get` request returns. Any delay in any one of the calls will cause a delay before that result (and the next) will appear.

If you don't mind using a "Loading Results" sort of thing with a preloader you could use css `display:none` or `opacity:0` on the container holding the results
and then use a function in the method callback to hide the preload message and show the results once the result returns.

Comment: so u mean to say i can return the output after insertion ? Could you please update my code and put in your answer block ?

Comment: Each `DeviceView.insert()` gets fired before the Method is complete and is immediately available to the UI.

You don't have to wait for the Method to return before the document will show up on the client side.

Comment: If you want to ONLY return the results that got inserted from that particular call and not make the collection available to the client, then waiting for the method to return and passing the array back is the best way... off the top of my head I can't think of a good way to do that without any type of delay. You'll always be limited by the response time of the resource you are making the `get` request to.

Comment: but i dont want to query the db. I want to show the data that comes from api , cos insertion to db might be removed in future. For now i am inserting and want to publish the data that comes from api directly

Comment: Why do you want to add them into the database at all?